# MySQL Limiting a query to one consistent value

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database

My current query returns a table like:

```
+------------+
value1 | ....
value1 | ....
value2 | ....
value3 | ....
+------------+
```

I want:

```
+------------+
value1 | ....
value1 | ....
+------------+
```

I want to only receive all rows with the first value. Normally I would do a WHERE clause if I knew that value, and I cannot use a LIMIT because each value has a different number of rows.

Right now My query looks like:

```
SELECT u.*, n.something, w.* 
  FROM ... AS u, ... AS n, ... AS w 
 WHERE u.id = n.id 
   AND w.val = n.val 
   AND u.desc LIKE '%GET REQUEST VARIABLE%'
```

This works great, except I get way too many rows and using PHP to do this ruins code portability and is superfluous.

Comment: So... do you want a random value from the original query, or did you have something more specific in mind?

Comment: I want the first group of results, in this case value1, but they are usually long descriptions.

Comment: You want the IDs of all duplicate value1's on a search for like 'value%' that might also match value2, value3 etc?

Comment: What does "first" mean to you? First returned? First alphabetically? First in some other way?

Comment: So the query also matches value2, value3, etc because say my query is "foo" I may have multiple occurence, but I only want the first set of rows that happens to have value1, not the rest (value2, value3, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure but I think you might be able to get it with this:

```
SELECT u.*, n.something, w.*
FROM ... AS u
JOIN ... AS n ON u.id = n.id
JOIN ... AS w ON w.val = n.val
JOIN (
  SELECT col
  FROM ... AS u2
  WHERE u2.desc LIKE ?
  LIMIT 1
) AS u2 ON u2.col = u.col
```

where the `...` in the inner `SELECT` is the same table aliased to `u` before.

**EDIT:** One more thing: I assumed `col` is different for different `desc` values; if not, you would have to repeat the `WHERE` in the outer `SELECT` as well.

(If you're not familiar with prepared statements, `?` is where your `'%...%'` would go... and don't forget to escape it against [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/); if you are, of course, the library will do it for you :) )